# React what is the correct shape of data in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i am updating non trivial data in react state and i am not sure what should data looks like. I am updating timetable item. It looks like this:
[image]

I am updating everyTime subject only in some day and slot.

my function looks like this now

```
 updateColumn(newSubject,dayId,order){
        console.log("tu som");
        console.log(newSubject);
        console.log(dayId);
        console.log(order);
        console.log(this.state.schedule);
        //Problematic part:
        let newSchedule = this.state.schedule;
        newSchedule.days[dayId].slots[order] = newSubject;
        console.log("newSchedule");
        console.log(newSchedule);

        this.setState({schedule:this.state.schedule});
        console.log("this new state");
        console.log(this.state.schedule);
        //State changed but error shows
    }
```

I tried this but this is not correct becouse slots and days are arrays of objects.

```
this.setState({...this.state, schedule: {
  ...this.state.schedule,
  days: {
     ...this.state.schedule.days,
     [dayId]: dayId,
     slots: {
      ...this.state.schedule.days.slots,
      [order] : newSubject
   }
})
```

How it should be right ways please?

Comment: Kind of hard to understand. How does your state look and how should your state look after updating it?

Comment: You don't have to do `this.setState({...this.state,` because setState merges the state it doesn't overwrite the entire state with what you return.

Comment: ```newSchedule.days[dayId].slots[order] = newSubject;```

Comment: This is what i need to update

Comment: other data stayed same

Comment: There is a image how my state is look like

Comment: Okay can you tell me what is `dayId` and `order` in `newSchedule.days[dayId].slots[order]`? Are they indexes or properties?

Comment: index. For example order : 1 (slots order in timetable e.g. 2. hour)and day : 0-4 (represent mondy to friday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const updatedSchedule = { ...prevState.schedule };
  const updatedDays = [...updatedSchedule.days];
  const updatedDay = {...updatedDays[dayId]};
  const updatedSlots = [...updatedDay.slots];
  updatedSlots[order].subject = newSubject;

  updatedDay.slots = updatedSlots;
  updatedDays[dayId] = updatedDay;
  updatedSchedule.days = updatedDays;
  return {
    schedule: updatedSchedule
  };
})
```

assuming `dayId` and `order` are indexes.

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for. Thx man i was looking for answer for hours... Anyway updatedSlots[order] = newSubject should be ```  updatedSlots[order].subject = newSubject```. Otherwise it cause undefined error in child ocmponent. Thx

Comment: Yeah, I didn't properly study your state's structure. Glad this helped you. Will update my answer. I also changed `const updatedDay = updatedDays[dayId];` to `const updatedDay = {...updatedDays[dayId]};` make sure to change that too.